# I have opened a Laravel project in to visual studio after namespace

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio, controller, namespaces

I have opened a Laravel project in visual studio after that namespace should be in first line, error occurring is shown below and there is no white space before and after php tag.

[image: screenshot of code is here]

Comment: It means there is space before `<?php` tag @neha di

Comment: Also please always include code instead image.

Comment: no there is no space before <?php tag

Comment: Do you remember when it was working and after adding some code it is giving this error?

Comment: Do you also check there is no space b/with `<?php` tag and `namespace` ? try to remove if any place it as in first line ?

Comment: yesterday it was in working condition, but today in morning there is some .vscode->settings.josn file includes by visual studio.

Comment: yes i have checked there is no space between [<?php] and [namespace]

Comment: Please share your code as a text instead image , and keep `namespace` as first line

Comment: <?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

Comment: If still not fixed then I can suggest you to go back when it was working and step  step check again

Comment: not fixed yet I've tried everything please help

Comment: If you worked on any other file then also check at last line, there should not be extra space at all

Comment: checked....no space

Comment: No di there is some space, if you are using git go to last commit . Revert all changes you did from last working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved this problem to put my controller code into https://phpcodechecker.com/

It removes the white space and pastes it back to my file.